# Asymptotic Behavior of Probabilities mapped to Discrete Outcomes

Tags: multinomial-distribution, mathematical-statistics

I'm having trouble finding a solution to the following problem:

Assume that there are $N$ observations and each observation is associated with $K$ probabilities.  For each $i \in N$, the probabilities sum to 1.  Given the probabilities for each individual, I want to calculate the probability that the first option occurs more across the $N$ individuals than all other options.  I can bootstrap the answer, but as $N$ increases, this becomes an unnecessarily difficult exercise.

Can anyone think of theory or point me to a paper that might have this result?